# How are assembly directives instructed?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, directive

To elaborate the question on the title, suppose I declared the following array in C++,

```
int myarr[10];
```

This disassembles to the following in x86

```
myarr:
    .zero   40
```

Now, AFAIK this `.zero` directive is used for convention and is not an instruction. Then, how exactly is this directive translated to x86(or any other architecture, it's not the emphasis here) instructions? Because, for all we know the CPU can only execute instructions. So I guess these directives are somehow translated to instructions, am I correct?

I could generalize the question by also asking how `.word` `.long` etc. are translated into instructions, but I think it is clear.

Comment: Just like any language, assembly has to have ways to declare (global) data -- these are not instructions, just values that go into memory and get assigned addresses.  The code (the instructions) use such data as variables, so the instructions reference this data by their memory addresses.  Uses of labels in assembly code instructions get translated into numbers representing addresses in the machine code instructions.  (Data can also be initialized as pointer to data or to code as well.)

Comment: these directives are not instructions and are not going to be, this is data not code you defined some amount of data, so the compiler created some amount of data.  had you created something that does some action on data, then the compiler would have created some instructions (if those actions didnt get optimized away)

Comment: @ErikEidt  And how exactly do they "go into memory"? Isn't the processor supposed to store them into memory via instructions? What I understand from your comment is that those declarations have nothing to do with the processor or instructions.

Comment: They go as data values into the program file, and when run, the program file is loaded into the memory of a process (by the operating system).  The program files stores the initial values for the state of a program.  Some of the initial values are machine code instructions (t be executed), and some  of the initial values are data, like globals, string literals, etc.. to be referenced by the instructions as data.

Comment: First, an assembler (or compiler) reads the data declarations as text in the source file: of each and every value, every byte in string literals, etc.., and creates a mock up of a chunk of data that the program (being created) wants.  Similar to how an assembler or compiler work on code, reading code statements and creating a mock up of a chunk of code.  These mock up chunks are gathered together and merged (code with code, data with data) by the linker into the program file.  These chunks, when found in object files or program files, are called sections -- see @Eric's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The output of the assembler is an object module. In the object module are representations of various sections for a program. Each section has a size, some attributes, and possibly some data to be put into the section.

For example, a section may be a few thousand bytes, have attributes indicating it contains instructions for execution, and have data that consists of those instructions. Another section might be several hundred bytes but have no data—it is just space to be allocated when the program starts. Another section might be very big and have non-zero data that contains its initial values when the program starts.

To assemble a `.zero 40` directive, the compiler just includes forty bytes of zeros in the section it is currently building. When it writes the final output, it will include those zeros in that section. Data directives like this and `.word` and such simply tell the assembler what data to put into its output.

Comment: "four bytes of zeros" - Do you mean 40? Because each `int` is 4 bytes and there's 10 of them so 40 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int stuff[10];
void fun ( void )
{
    unsigned int r;
    for(r=0;r<10;r++) stuff[r]=r;
}
```

using ARM...

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   4:   e59f2010    ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; 1c <fun+0x1c>
   8:   e5a23004    str r3, [r2, #4]!
   c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  10:   e353000a    cmp r3, #10
  14:   1afffffb    bne 8 <fun+0x8>
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  1c:   00000ffc

Disassembly of section .bss:

00001000 <stuff>:
    ...
```

The array stuff is simply data it is not code it is not instructions and won't be, the directive in question you asked about won't become code, it cants it is data.

If you want to see code, instructions, then you need to put lines of high level language that act on data for example as shown here.  And in that case the compiler generates code.

Looking at this compilers actual output (comments and other non-essentials removed)

```
fun:
    mov r3, #0
    ldr r2, .L6
.L2:
    str r3, [r2, #4]!
    add r3, r3, #1
    cmp r3, #10
    bne .L2
    bx  lr
.L7:
    .align  2
.L6:
    .word   stuff-4
...
    .comm   stuff,40,4
```

the .comm in this case is how they declared the data that represents the array in the high level language.  and the other stuff is mostly code.  the .align is there so that the address of L6 is aligned so that you don't get an alignment fault when you try to read it.

.word is a directive, what you see here is .text vs .data while it is just one simple C program with the array and the code right there next to each other.  because code can possibly live in read only memory like flash and data needs to be in read/write memory and at compile time the compiler doesn't know where the data is relative to the code, so it generates an abstraction by placing a read only word in the code that the linker fills in later, the code is generic and whatever the linker puts in there it uses.  The linker "places" .text and .bss in this case it wasn't initialized so it isn't actually .data and then makes that connection in the code.

labels are directives if you will so that the programmer or code generator (compiler) doesn't have to count instructions or overall size of instructions to make relative jumps.  Let the tools do that for you.

```
  1c:   00000ffc 

Disassembly of section .bss:

00001000 <stuff>:
    ...
```

and based on the way I linked this (non actually a working) program stuff is the only data item in this program and the linker placed it where I asked at address 0x1000, then went back and filled in that .word directive to be stuff-4 which is 0xFFC so that the code as compiled works.

directives are not part of the instruction set but are part of the assembly language, note that assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool, not the instruction set/target.  There are countless different x86 assembly languages and AT&T vs Intel is not the primary difference, the directives how you define a label, how you indicate a number is hex or decimal, because of the vagueness of the instructions as defined in the early docs lots of adjectives if you will to be able to specify which mov instruction you were actually after and even though that's part of the instruction and not a directive those adjectives varied across assembly languages.  ARM, MIPS, and many if not most others have had tools created with incompatible assembly languages.   .zero for example being one of those incompatible things.

In any case an assembly language in question needs to be able to define data and then have a way for code to reference that data in order to make useful programs.

The notion of a one to one line of assembly language to instructions is very misleading and don't get fooled by it, today's compilers generate almost as much non-code as code in their output.  Lots of directives and other information.